# Euclidean Distance between a vector x and S

Tags: linear-algebra

How would I go about finding the euclidean distance of a vector **x** onto a subspace $S$? I was thinking about using a projection matrix, then projecting **x** onto $S$. Then  take **v**= **x**-**u**, where **u** is the vector found by projecting **x** onto $S$. Then just find the magnitude of the vector **v**. Is this thought process correct?

Comment: Please clarify: What is S? What do you mean by projecting x onto B?

Comment: I did have my letters mixed up. S is a subspace.